# C# and Outlook Addin: Parsing all 'Received' fields from header for IMAP

Tags: c#, email, outlook, imap

I have searched for my problem and couldn't find any answer to it. There are similar questions to this, but not specifically mine. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

I am working on an outlook add-in using C# (vs 2010). I will need to parse all of the "Received:" lines out of the header. Currently I am testing this on Outlook 2010.

By default, outlook will strip the header and keeps only what it needs. So no matter how to configure it, it will strip the header and if there are say 4 "Received" lines in the header, Outlook only keeps the last one.

Following the registry modification explained [here](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/701), will partially solve the problem as it will retain the header only when Outlook is set to POP3. IMAP still has all of the "Received:" lines removed (except the last one).

The following is how I am getting the header using C# (this is part of a code that is called every time an email is selected in outlook):

```
const string PR_MAIL_HEADER_TAG = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E";
Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
Outlook.PropertyAccessor oPA = mailItem.PropertyAccessor as Outlook.PropertyAccessor;
string Header = (string)oPA.GetProperty(PR_MAIL_HEADER_TAG);
```

This will give me the header, but only what Outlook has kept, nothing from the original email.

To clarify, opening the email and choosing File -> Properties -> Internet Header also only shows what is left from the header after outlook's modifications, not the original one.

The outlook option -> Action -> Other actions -> View Source also does not reveal what I am looking for.

So I am basically looking for a way to read IMAP original email source using within C#.

Comment: Are you sure there are Received fields at all? IMAP makes it easy for a client to retrieve less than the entire messages, and many clients do that. Try looking at the IMAP commands sent to the server, if you see something like FETCH ... BODY[HEADER.FIELDS(To From Reply-By)] then Outlook retrieves only the named fields.